# Looping through .xlsx files using pandas, only does first file

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.4

My ultimate goal is to merge the contents of a folder full of .xlsx files into one big file.

I thought the below code would suffice, but it only does the first file, and I can't figure out why it stops there. The files are small (~6 KB), so it shouldn't be a matter of waiting. If I print f_list, it shows the complete list of files. So, where am I going wrong? *To be clear, there is no error returned, it just does not do the entire for loop.* I feel like there should be a simple fix, but being new to Python and coding, I'm having trouble seeing it.

I'm doing this with Anaconda on Windows 8.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
f_list = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\me\\dt\\xx\\*.xlsx")  # creates my file list
all_data = pd.DataFrame()             # creates my DataFrame

for f in f_list:                      # basic for loop to go through file list but doesn't
    df = pd.read_excel(f)             # reads .xlsx file
    all_data = all_data.append(df)    # appends file contents to DataFrame
all_data.to_excel("output.xlsx")      # creates new .xlsx
```

Edit with new information:

After trying some of the suggested changes, I noticed the output claiming the files are empty, except for 1 of them which is slightly larger than the others. If I put them into the DataFrame, it claims the DataFrame is empty. If I put it into the dict, it claims there are no values associated. Could this have something to do with the file size? Many, if not most, of these files have 3-5 rows with 5 columns. The one it does see has 12 rows.

Comment: Have you tried printing a count of iterations through the for loop? Print df each time through? Print all_data each time through?  Simple steps to troubleshoot a bit further

Comment: You're probably appending all the index values together but you should still get all dfs appended together are you sure the final  is not the correct size? as an aside can you try this line instead `all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True) ` this is assuming that you're just intending to add rows and not new columns

Comment: @CharlieHaley -- I know it's seeing all of the file. But it claims they are empty. I'll edit the OP soon to include this new information.

Comment: @EdChum -- I tried that change, but the result is the same. I think the issue is it thinks to files are empty. I'll post the new information shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend reading the DataFrames into a dict:

```
sheets = {f: pd.read_excel(f) for f in f_list}
```

For one thing this is *very* easy to debug: just inspect the dict in the REPL.

Another is that you can then concat these into one DataFrame efficiently in one pass:

```
pd.concat(sheets.values())
```

*Note: This is significantly faster than append, which has to allocate a temporary DataFrame at each append-call.*

---

An alternative issue is that your glob may not be picking up all the files, you should check that it is by printing `f_list`.

Comment: thank you for your input so far. I was able to get everything into a dict, but when I printed it to check, it claimed all of the files, except for the first one, are empty. I'm updating the OP shortly. Also, the glob is successfully getting all the files.

Comment: @chhillout that'll do it. This may be better as a new question (specifically, "why is my spreadsheet empty"? ... perhaps it's looking at the wrong sheet by default?

Comment: Thank you, Andy! I'll get a new question up as time allows.

Comment: Please feel free to CC me with a link here when you do. Although it's not fully answered yet, when it is, please click 'accept' :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/184179

Comment: I'll be happy to once I get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Not sure how to copy you so posting the link to the new question here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852173/why-is-my-spreadsheet-xlsx-empty>

Comment: I do have a follow-up question: How do I save the Dict into an .XLSX file after adding all the data? Should I create a new question for this?

Comment: @chhillout yes please

Comment: Posted about saving the dict here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046552/saving-a-dict-into-a-xlsx-using-python-pandas