# Saving a dictionary into an .XLSX

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

Using Python + Pandas, is there a quick and easy way to save a Dict (consisting of file names for the keys and several columns of data for the values) into an .XLSX file?

After some research, I tried converting it into a Pandas DataFrame (because I know you can write to an .XLSX file from a Pandas DataFrame) using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
f_list = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\me\\dt\\xx\\*.xlsx")

sheets = {f: pd.read_excel(f) for f in f_list}
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sheets, orient = "index")
new_df.to_excel("ALL_RUCDR_DATA.xlsx")
```

but I get this error:

> TypeError: Unsupported type (class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame') in write().

I know it will create the dictionary successfully, and it seems to create the DataFrame, but why won't it create the file?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Could you give a simple example dict which demonstrates this, e.g. `sheets = {"a": pd.DataFrame([[1]], columns=["A"]), "b": pd.DataFrame([[2]], columns=["B"])}` ? I think this from_dict method doesn't do what you think it does...

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-excel-files-to-disk) suggest you do this with the following:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx') as writer:
    for (sheet_name, df) in sheets.items():
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

---

The error occurs as `from_dict` on a dict of DataFrames creates a strange DataFrame where each element is a DataFrame:

```
In [11]: sheets = {"a": pd.DataFrame([[1]], columns=["A"]), "b": pd.DataFrame([[2], [3]], columns=["B"])}

In [12]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sheets, orient='index')
Out[12]:
                0
b     B
0  2
1  3
a          A
0  1

In [13]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sheets, orient='index').applymap(type)
Out[13]:
                                       0
b  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
a  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

This isn't going to map to a excel sheet as that expects single values (e.g. int/float/string) as the elements.

If you want to merge/concat/join the data from your dictionary into a single file, checkout the [merging section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) (think of this in terms of pandas DataFrames rather than spreadsheets).